# Multiple calls to select2() on select input makes it disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How to reproduce :

Go to http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-latest.html with Chrome.

Open web development console, type :

$("#e1").select2()

> > "TypeError: Object -1 has no method 'show'"

and the first select disappears, why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the second call the code wants to destroy the old generated dropdown before creating a new one. It does so before initializing itself properly.

The relevant code is in the "delete" function around line 645:

```
 if (select2 !== undefined) {
    select2.container.remove();
    select2.dropdown.remove();
    select2.opts.element
       .removeData("select2")
       .unbind(".select2")
       .attr("tabIndex", this.elementTabIndex)   <--- fail here
       .show();
```

Trouble is it calls `.attr("tabIndex", this.elementTabIndex)` while `this.elementTabIndex` is `undefined` and `.attr(name, undefined)` is equivalent to `.attr(name)`, thus returning the attribute itself (instead of the jquery element. So you got the attribute value `'-1'`, and `'-1'.show()` makes no sense then, of course.

as a kludge, use `.attr("tabIndex", this.elementTabIndex || -1)`.
a better fix might be is to call `destroy` only after `this.elementTabIndex` is initialized. I am not sure if the call to `attr` is really needed in the `destroy` at all, but then I cannot claim I understand the code.